# What will be found in the table of virtual functions of the class child. It is empty or not created at all?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, vtable

There are two classes, the second class will inherit the first. The base class has virtual functions and in the derived no virtual functions. What will be found in the table of virtual functions of the class child. It is empty or not created at all?

```
class base
{
private:
int m_d;
public:
virtual void foo();
virtual void bar();
};

class derived : public base
{
int m_b;
void baz();
};
```

Comment: [Recommended reading about vtable layout](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html)

Comment: About an hour ago, I was interviewed by phone, on this question, I replied that the virtual function table of the inherited class  will be empty, it is very rough and inaccurate answer ?

Comment: `The base class has virtual functions and in the derived no virtual functions.` No, the derived class **does** have virtual functions - the ones that it _inherits_ from the base. Whether it adds any new ones of its own doesn't matter. This is needed so that code working with a reference- or pointer-to-base can still execute virtual functions if passed a derived class; that's the point.

Answer (score 3):

The vtable is an implementation detail of C++ compilers, so there is no standard answer. It would make sense with respect to minimizing indirections that each vtable contains the full set of virtual functions of all its bases, but again, this is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution is to have a vtable per class, so the derived class will have a separate vtable identical to the vtable of the base class. This is done so that it is possible to find which class it is (as when doing `dynamic_cast`) just by having a vpointer value.